# Reversal law in matrices

Tags: matrices, solution-verification, inverse

> Prove that if  $A$ and $B$ are two invertible matrices , then $AB$ is also invertible and $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$

Given that $\det A,\det B\neq 0\implies \det AB\neq 0\implies AB$ is invertible.

Let $C=AB$

Then we have a matrix $C^{-1} $ such that $CC^{-1}=I$

$$(AB)(AB)^{-1}=I$$   which on first pre-multiplying both sides with $A^{-1}$ and then pre-multiplying with  $B^{-1}  $ gives $ (AB)^{-1}=A^{-1}B^{-1}$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You say "then pre-multiplying with $B^{-1}$", but you post-multiplied by $B^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you premultiply first by $A^{-1}$ and then by $B^{-1}$, you end up premultiplying by $B^{-1}A^{-1}$, not by $A^{-1}B^{-1}$.

But this is really just the associative law.

$$(AB)(B^{-1}A^{-1})=A(BB^{-1})A^{-1}=AIA^{-1}=AA^{-1}=I.$$

In other words, if you multiply $AB$ by $B^{-1}A^{-1}$, you get the identity matrix, so $B^{-1}A^{-1}$ satisfies the definition of $(AB)^{-1}$ and $AB$ must be invertible.  Note that this proof works in any structure that follows the associative law and in which inverses are unique if they exist.  You don't need to use determinants.